# read a csv to df with a different columns order

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large CSV file that is created through someone else's script with output columns named 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C'. 
Is there a way to read it from CSV directly as 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the order of DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping columns in the specified order when using UseCols in Pandas Read\_CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024406/keeping-columns-in-the-specified-order-when-using-usecols-in-pandas-read-csv)

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution that works with pandas 0.25.1

CSV file with output columns named 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C'
Read it from CSV directly as 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

It reads the CSV columns in the given order into a pandas DataFrame named 'csv'
Both the index_col=[] and the usecols=[] have to containe the same list order.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) cannot do it, idea with `usecols` also not working:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""D;B;A;C
0;a;4;7;1
1;b;5;8;3
2;c;4;9;5
3;d;5;4;7
4;e;5;2;1
5;f;4;3;0"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
print (df)
   D  B  A  C
0  0  a  4  7
1  1  b  5  8
2  2  c  4  9
3  3  d  5  4
4  4  e  5  2
5  5  f  4  3
```

Solution is change order by list or sorting index:

```
df = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  4  a  7  0
1  5  b  8  1
2  4  c  9  2
3  5  d  4  3
4  5  e  2  4
5  4  f  3  5
```

---

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  4  a  7  0
1  5  b  8  1
2  4  c  9  2
3  5  d  4  3
4  5  e  2  4
5  4  f  3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not asking how to change column order in Pandas, but would like to change it before reading in, possibly to reduce memory use. (If not see @jezrael's answer.)

Best is to do it with `csv` before reading into Pandas. Example:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33002011)

In terms of time, quickest is doing it as CSV (I tested with a very small csv file):

```
%%time
df = pd.read_csv('r.csv')[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

CPU times: user 3.53 ms, sys: 1.48 ms, total: 5 ms
Wall time: 3.79 ms

%%time
df=pd.read_csv('r.csv')[df.columns[::-1]]

CPU times: user 4.75 ms, sys: 2.01 ms, total: 6.76 ms
Wall time: 5.13 ms

%%time
cols=list('ABCD')
pd.concat([pd.read_csv('r.csv', usecols=[x]) for x in cols], axis=1)

CPU times: user 8.98 ms, sys: 2.25 ms, total: 11.2 ms
Wall time: 9.88 ms

%%time
df = pd.read_csv('r.csv').sort_index(axis=1)

CPU times: user 4.21 ms, sys: 1.88 ms, total: 6.09 ms
Wall time: 4.65 ms

%%time
with open('r.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:

    fieldnames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
df = pd.read_csv('reordered.csv')

CPU times: user 3.29 ms, sys: 1.91 ms, total: 5.2 ms
Wall time: 3.83 ms
```

Comment: I do not care about that file itself, it will be deleted soon. I just want to read it in the order i need.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to read a single column at a time and store in a list comprehension and `concat` the result:

```
In[121]:
t="""D,B,A,C
4,2,1,3"""
cols = list('ABCD')
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), usecols=[x]) for x in cols], axis=1)

Out[121]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
```

However, I think that it's easier to just sort it by sub-selecting the columns in the order you want after reading normally:

```
df = df[['A','B','C','D']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add .reset_index() in order to reset the in the index_col set index.

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], usecols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
df=df[df.columns[::-1]]
```