# Rearrange columns in Pandas upon reading csv / importing data

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a csv that had 20 columns. I used the following to create a df to select only the columns that I needed:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data/employees.csv", 
    usecols = ['ID','FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME','SALARY'],
    index_col = ['ID'])
```

However, the order displayed when I call df is not the same as the one that I specified when reading the CSV file. Note how I used index_col to change the index. How can I choose the order when I'm first importing the data?

Comment: This post might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024406/keeping-columns-in-the-specified-order-when-using-usecols-in-pandas-read-csv

Comment: That was in the documentation but it didn't work because I used index_col to use the ID as the index of the data frame.

Comment: Try this - `df = pd.read_csv('./data/employees.csv',  usecols=['ID', 'FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'SALARY'], index_col=['ID'])[['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME',  'SALARY']]`

Comment: It looks like the column that you specify in index_col should not be placed in the sort that you specify at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You are welcome !